# Application of Hahn-Banach to Linear Functional Extension

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am currently enrolled in a functional analysis course and am experiencing some troubles with applying the Hahn-Banach theorem we discussed with regards to extending linear functional. In particular, we were given this practice problem:

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined $L(x_{1},x_{2}) = 3x_{1} + 4x_{2}.$ Let $C$ be the norm of $L.$ Evaluate $C$, and then construct explicitly an extension $\tilde{L}:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the same norm.

I am going to present my logic and attempt at the problem, and would appreciate any advice!

Firstly, to determine $|||L|||,$ the operator norm of $L,$ by definition we determine the supremum of $|L(x)|$ over all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $||x|| = 1$ where $||\ ||$ is the usual Euclidean norm. In other words, all $x$ that lie on the unit circle. I determined that the supremum was 5. This is where I am having some difficulty in applying the Hahn-Banach theorem. It says that if $L(x) \leq p(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2},$ then we can extend it to a function $\tilde{L}(x + th) = L(x) + \alpha t$ such that $\tilde{L}\leq p(x)$ on now $\mathbb{R}^{3}.$ However, I supposed that $p(x)$ was to be taken as the Euclidean norm, and it is not true that $L(x)\leq ||x||?$ Nonetheless, I attempted to extend $L$ as follows.

To extend $L$ to a linear functional $\tilde{L}$ from $\mathbb{R}^{3},$ we need to have it be 
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{L}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) := L(x + x_{3}t) = L(x) + x_{3}\alpha
\end{equation*}
where $\alpha = L(t),\ x = (x_{1},x_{2})$ and $x_{3}\in\mathbb{R}.$ Moreover, it must be such that $|||\tilde{L}||| = 5.$ To do this, as the operator norm is take over all $||x|| = 1,$ we must consider $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2} = 1.$ That is, along the sphere of radius 1. With this, to determine the maximum value of $\tilde{L},$ it will be more convenient to convert from Cartesian coordinates into spherical with $\rho = 1$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ and $\phi\in[0,\pi].$ After this, our linear functional $\tilde{L}$ becomes
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{L}(\theta,\phi) = \sin{\phi}(3\cos{\theta} + 4\sin{\theta}) + \alpha\cos{\phi}
\end{equation*}
To determine its maximum value, we must determine when both the partial with respect to $\theta$ and with respect to $\phi$ are both zero to obtain candidates of being a maximum. These partials are,
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{L}_{\theta} = \sin{\phi}(4\cos{\theta}-3\sin{\theta}),\quad \tilde{L}_{\phi} = \cos{\phi}(3\cos{\theta}+4\sin{\theta})-\alpha\sin{\phi}
\end{equation*}
The first partial yields $\phi = 0,\pi$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}{\frac{4}{3}}.$ When considering $\phi = 0,\pi,$ the corresponding $\theta$ the partial with respect to $\phi$ yields $\theta = \tan^{-1}{\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)}.$ As for $\theta = \tan^{-1}{\frac{4}{3}},$ the corresponding $\phi$ obtained from $\tilde{L}_{\phi}$ is $\phi = \tan^{-1}{\frac{5}{\alpha}}.$ Now, it is then necessary to determine the second-order partials and calculate $D = \tilde{L}_{\theta\theta}\tilde{L}_{\phi\phi} - \tilde{L}_{\theta\phi}^{2}$ for all potential 3 points, but simply plugging in the values yields a clear result that the maximum occurs at the point $\left(\tan^{-1}{\frac{4}{3}},\tan^{-1}{\frac{5}{\alpha}}\right),$ which in turn is
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{L}\left(\tan^{-1}{\frac{4}{3}},\tan^{-1}{\frac{5}{\alpha}}\right) = \sin{\tan^{-1}{\frac{5}{\alpha}}}\left(3\cos{\tan^{-1}{\frac{4}{3}}} + 4\sin{\tan^{-1}{\frac{4}{3}}}\right) + \alpha\cos{\tan^{-1}{\frac{5}{\alpha}}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 = \sqrt{25 + \alpha^{2}}
\end{equation*}
Thus, we obtain that
\begin{equation*}
|||\tilde{L}||| = \mathrm{sup}_{||x|| = 1}|\tilde{L}(x)| = \sqrt{25+\alpha^{2}}
\end{equation*}
but for $|||\tilde{L}|||$ to be equal to 5, we must then require that $\alpha = 0.$

So in other words, the extending linear functional would just be the same $L$ given, but that doesn't seem right. I feel that my doubt particularly stems from my uncertainty in understanding the HB theorem. I would like to say I understand the proof and how to show that such an extension exists, but we did not discuss examples/applications on a problem like this, so I don't know where I stand. Moreover, the professor asked what about extending it from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to $\ell^{2}?$ After this first step, however, I would imagine my result would be the same. I would appreciate any help and recommendations to better understand the Hahn-Banach theorem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way of thinking about this is through orthogonality. So, let's look at the more general idea about Hahn-Banach for Hilbert spaces.

One can prove Hahn-Banach in Hilbert spaces a little easier. Suppose that we have a continuous linear functional $f$ of norm 1 defined on a closed subspace $B$ of $H$, where $H$ is separable (for example). Then we can choose a vector $x$ which is orthogonal to $B$, say, $\|x\| = 1$ and $\langle x, b \rangle = 0$ for every $b \in B$.

To extend $f$ we define $f(b + tx) = f(b) + \alpha t$ for some $\alpha$. Our claim is that we can choose $\alpha$ such that $\|f\| = 1$.

So, suppose $b+tx$ has norm 1. This means that $\langle b+tx, b+tx \rangle = 1$, so expanding and noticing that the cross term cancels (and supposing we're in the real case) we get $\langle b,b \rangle + t^2 = 1$, namely, $\|b\| \leq 1$

Then $f(b+tx) = f(b) + \alpha t \leq \|b\| + \alpha t$. So if $\alpha = 0$ then $f(b + tx) \leq \|b\| \leq \sqrt{\|b\|^2 + t^2} = \|b + t x\|$. So we can extend one dimension (using the orthogonal dimension) and keep going (separability means induction probably suffices.)

The question is **why does this not work in Banach and locally convex spaces?**

The issue comes down to orthogonality. The key point in this proof that we had that isn't present in Banach spaces is the following: if $\|b+tx\| \leq 1$ then $\|b\| \leq 1$.

However, this isn't true in general. I will give you an artificial example that perhaps helps: suppose that we took $\mathbb{R}^3$, $B = $span$\{e_1,e_2\}$ as the unit basis vectors and for $x_3$ we took $-0.4 (e_1 + e_2) + c e_3$ (where $c$ is chosen so that this has norm 1).

Then if we look at the vector $u = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} (e_1 + e_2)$ and look at $u + x_3$ we get that this has norm less than 0.6 [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%29%2F2+%7B%7B1%7D%2C%7B1%7D%2C%7B0%7D%7D+-+0.4+%7B%7B1%7D%2C%7B1%7D%2C%7B0%7D%7D+%2B+sqrt%281-%282*0.4%29%5E2%29+%7B%7B0%7D%2C%7B0%7D%2C%7B1%7D%7D) is the computation sadly.

So in this case, if I had any functional $f$ defined on $B$, if I decided to extend it to all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ through setting $\alpha = 0$ the norm could increase: as a very concrete example suppose that $f(u)$ was the maximum we could get, and $f(u) = 1$. Then $\|f\| = 1$, but if $\alpha = 0$ then $f(u+x_3) = f(u) = 1$, but $\|u+x_3\| < 1$. Thus the norm has increased.

I hope this helps: orthogonality makes a lot of things in life easier, Hahn-Banach is just one of them.

Comment: (What I said about Hilbert spaces is replicating the proof in the Banach case: I don't doubt there are faster ways of seeing it through Riesz representation.)

Comment: I still don't quite understand the extension on an example, however. I understand the "proof" you gave with Hilbert spaces, but in the example you provided where are you extending from? I assume you're beginning with a function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined as $(x,y)\mapsto -0.4(x+y).$ But in this case the operator norm of such a function would be 0.4$\sqrt{2},$ would it not? And to extend it to be defined on $\mathbb{R}^{3},$ c = 0 would still result in the same norm, so I don't understand your comment in the second to last sentence.

Comment: In the example I'm not extending anything, I'm simply showing that the statement $\|b+tx\| \leq 1 \implies \|b\| \leq 1$ isn't necessarily true if we choose $x$ 'badly'.

Comment: I'm talking about any functional $f$ in this case, I'll edit it to make it a little clearer (or make it worse). I've added a specific example: I hope it helps. It somewhat fogs the intention of what I'm saying though. Also what I said in the Hilbert space case is genuinely a proof.